# RichText WYSIWYG editor without UI (JavaScript API only)

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I am looking for a very clean project to add cross-browser JavaScript API to contenteditable div.

If it has UI, then it should be possible not to load it (as opposed to disabling it) or completely remove from sources.

I am looking for basic features really without huge focus on backward-compatibility but rather a cleaner code.

Some of the features, I would expect from this API would be:

- Insert HTML snippet at the position of the cursor
- Clean up contents after paste (such as spans and font sizes)
- Return node, where cursor currently is positioned
- Add new item to item list

I suppose I could code them with some jQuery, but if someone have it, why not re-use it.

Comment: this seems like an oxymoron: WYSIWYG editor without UI?

Comment: what i meant - without toolbar, popups, layouts, drop downs. Only API.

Comment: Well, you could just set the `contentEditable` attribute on a `<div>` element....

Comment: You don't make it clear what you are expecting this API to do.  If you are looking for an API to manipulate a contenteditable it is called the `DOM`.

Comment: Yeah, but when it comes to ranges and other things browsers behave differently, so I would prefer if that would be abstracted. I'll try to update question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the one Google use -

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_editor.html

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/field_basic.html

If your concern about cleaner code relates to maintainability/extensibility then all the code in the Closure library is well documented and all variables/methods are verbose in their naming (this is because the Closure Compiler will take care of minifying them for the client).

Comment: that's more or less what i'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Both links are invalid, looking for a standalone version of the editor, if such thing exists.

Comment: http://google.github.io/closure-library/source/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html

Answer (score 1):

In CKEditor the UI and themes are defined as plugins and not part of the core, so if you have enough patience you could redefine them in any way that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Quill seems to be gaining good traction - https://github.com/quilljs/quill

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, it seems suitable: http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/reformator/

Source code: http://web.artlebedev.ru/tools/reformator/reformator.zip

PS. It's free for **non-commercial** use only.

Comment: 750 euros from artem, not bad. I don't need the UI though.

Answer (score 0):

**[TinyMice](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php)** is also good choice. It has jQuery API

Answer (score 0):

What about WYMEditor?

- http://www.wymeditor.org/
- https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor
- http://files.wymeditor.org/wymeditor/trunk/src/examples/12-custom-layout.html
- http://files.wymeditor.org/wymeditor/trunk/src/examples/

Comment: that's what i'm using now, but it's integrated with layout it seems, even if it's custom.

Comment: @romaninsh: Take a look in the "future" branch on github. The UI has been completely decoupled from the editor core. Or rather, it will be, as most of the UI isn't written yet.